Visual Studio Code -environment-cd: Usage DIRECTORY
I am try to launch Visual Studio Code for Renesas RA platoform. I am probably on last step to make Debug works. As you can see in attached file gdb server runs, but suddenly got error message from VS Code [-environment-cd: Usage DIRECTORY]. Probably launch.json is not fully defined but I dont know what it need to be done.
I use https://www.renesas.com/us/en/video/visual-studio-code-how-build-and-debug-vs-code-ra-family as an support.
I checked environment variables and gdb directories.
Image below:


"but suddenly got error message from VS Code." What error message?

-environment-cd: Usage DIRECTORY, edited post. - not enough rep to attach an image.
